# How do I serve static html files in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, static-files

I'm trying to serve some static html files in NGINX in the following folder and file naming convention.

```
/root/level-1/
/root/level-1a/
/root/level-1b/
/root/level-1.html
/root/level-1a.html
/root/level-1b.html
/root/level-1/foo.html
/root/level-1a/foo.html
/root/level-1b/foo.html

/root/level-1/level-2/
/root/level-1/level-2a/
/root/level-1/level-2b/
/root/level-1/level-2.html
/root/level-1/level-2a.html
/root/level-1/level-2b.html
/root/level-1/level-2/foo.html
/root/level-1/level-2a/foo.html
/root/level-1/level-2b/foo.html
```

All the paths in my html look something like this..

```
<a href="/root/level-1">
<a href="/root/level-1a">
<a href="/root/level-1b">
<a href="/root/level-1/foo">
<a href="/root/level-1a/foo">
<a href="/root/level-1b/foo">

<a href="/root/level-1/level-2">
<a href="/root/level-1/level-2a">
<a href="/root/level-1/level-2b">
<a href="/root/level-2/foo">
<a href="/root/level-2a/foo">
<a href="/root/level-2b/foo">

etc...
```

I'm trying to get NGINX to realise that when I have a URL that looks like this /root/level-1, it should try the file /root/level-1.html OR /root/level-1/level-2, it tries /root/level-1/level-2.html OR /root/level-1/level-2a/foo, it tries /root/level-1/level-2a/foo.html

This is what i have set for my location setting, I specifically trying to target the "root" location.

```
location ~ ^/root/.*$ {
  try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Right now when i try http://localhost/root/level-1 I get a 403 Forbidden and the URL in my browser ends up looking like this "http://localhost/root/level-1/" (the url now has a forward slash at the end of it).

I've tried several combinations but I think I'm missing a core understanding of what NGINX is doing and what I need to tell it to do in my situation.

Can any one help?

Comment: That `location` block looks fine, and it should not be able to generate a 403 response. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and check for other `server` and `location` blocks that may be processing the request. Check the access log and error log for more details.

Comment: There is no `index.html` inside `/level-1` folder - and by default directory index is disabled so nginX replies with 403. Either enable the autoindex or put `index.html` or set the `index` directive.

Answer (score 0):

This has got me 99% there

```
location ~ ^(?<path>/.*/)(?<file>[^/]+)/$ {
  try_files $uri $path$file.html $uri/ =404;
}
```

This URL is working `/root/level-1/level-2` but if I then try to get `/root/level-1/level-2/foo` it does not try and read `/root/level-1/level-2/foo.html` I get a 404 error.

I should add there is no foo folder in `/root/level-1/level-2` just `/root/level-1/level-2/foo.html`

I'm happy to hear from those more skilled than me if this solution can be improved on.